# rsync error: packet_write_wait

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync

I have been trying to automate a backup script which backs up my home directory (among other things) and I have been unable to fix the error

```
$ rsync --quiet -e ssh /home/user/bkp/user.tar.lrz user@ipAddress:/home
/user/AsusBackups
packet_write_wait: Connection to ipAddress port 22: Broken pipe
rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(820) [sender=3.1.3]
```

I have tried the following

1.) Connecting the server to the internet via an Ethernet cable (and from here on it is still connected via ethernet)

2.) Connecting the client to the internet via Ethernet cable

3.) Changing the port in which ssh is listening on, on the server

4.) Switching the client from a 5GHz WiFi channel to a 2.4GHz channel

5.) Adding the following on the clients /etc/ssh/ssh_config (starting from 120 working down to 10)

```
ServerAliveInterval 10
ServerAliveCountMzx 6
```

6.) Adding the following to the servers /etc/ssh/ssh_config

```
ClientAliverInterval 120
```

which yields a bad configuration option

7.) I have also tried rather than uploading an entire zip file issuing the following command  as it is in the wiki which yields the same issue

```
rsync -a --delete --quiet -e ssh /home/user user@ipAddress:/home/user/AsusBackups
```

I've also searched through google and really the only solution I came up with (aside from the ones I had already tried) was that maybe I have a lack of memory (though both effectively have 8G worth of memory).

Does anyone have any ideas? or possibly would be able to point me in the correct direction to solve this issue?

ps: Maybe its worth noting that the user.tar.lrz file is 29Gb in size
pss: I'm not sure if this is worth noting but the client has a stateful firewall set up but not the server (haven't gotten around to setting one up yet) though I don't imagine the client side firewall would change anything?

Comment: You should check the logs on the other side. And you probably got a "bad configuration option" because of the obvious typo.

Comment: `ClientAliveInterval 120` or `ClientAliverInterval 120` both give bad configuration option I originally had the typo and fixed it but that was my mistake for typing it again in the post! And as far as the logs I'm not sure which log I should look in most are data files that vim opens up as garbage